# What to do in Grand Canyon during Christmas to New Year's?

Tags: camping, backpacking, winter, grand-canyon

My friends and I are planning a trip to Grand Canyon from 29 December to 2nd Jan.  We won't go camping outside as we haven't got permit. We are thinking of camping in Mather and might go around small towns; Page or Flagstaff.

Is this a crazy idea in that - is there anything to do? Is camping possible during this time? We're planning this because me and my friends are going to celebrate Christmas in the west coast and want to get away from big cities during New Year's.

Answer (score 3):

Flagstaff is no longer a small town. The metro area has an estimated population of over [135,000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagstaff,_Arizona).

I suggest looking at the Grand Canyon [web site](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/lodging.htm) and making a reservation for lodging, either in the park or outside. This includes camping. As far as activities, you may a get a beautiful clear winter day. And you may not.

You are probably aware that all tourist facilities on the North Rim, which has a different and much colder weather system, are closed.